# Finding Canonical ID of the account using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm writing a custom S3 bucket policy using AWS that requires canonical ID of the account as a key parameter. I can get the account ID programmatically using cdk core. You may refer the python sample below.

```
cid = core.Aws.ACCOUNT_ID
```

Is there any way that we can get the same for canonical-ID.

**Update:**

I've found a workaround using S3API call. I've added the following code in my CDK stack. May be helpful to someone.

```py
def find_canonical_id(self):
   s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
   return s3_client.list_buckets()['Owner']['ID']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 ways to get the canonical ID (boto3):

**Method-1**  Through List bucket API (also mentioned by author in the update)

This method is [recommended by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/finding-canonical-user-id.html) as well.

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client("s3")

response = client.list_buckets()

canonical_id = response["Owner"]["ID"]
```

**Method-2**  Through Get bucket ACL API

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client("s3")

response = client.get_bucket_acl(
    Bucket='sample-bucket' # should be in your acct
)

canonical_id = response["Owner"]["ID"]
```